# What's the best way to add videos to questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

Often, a video can be a great help to visualise a problem.

But on many questions, the person asking just links to someserver.sometld/somedir/somevideo.someEsotericFormat, which might not even be playable by other users (Let alone downloading huge files from untrustable sources).

Wouldn't the best way be to upload the video to a streaming website (e.g. youtube) and link to that?

Should advice like this be added to 'how to ask questions'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While "best" is certainly subjective, I think we can agree that streaming is indeed better than having to download a tens- or hundreds-of-MBs file just to watch it.

Perhaps someone posting a video like that isn't aware of the ease of streaming video sites. Feel free to suggest to them, via a comment, that they upload the video to the streaming site of your choice. You might also gently indicate that you are much more inclined to watch a streaming video than to download a huge video file.